# problema con metodo async

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, asincronismo

Tengo el siguiente problema: he creado una clase Contenedor que luego la exporto con module. En esta clase tengo un metodo "asyn GetAll()"

```
async getAll(){
    try {
        let contenido = await fs.promises.readFile(`./${this.archivo}`,'utf-8')
        let content = JSON.parse(contenido)
        return content
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

para probarlo en vez del return habia colocado un console.log y me retornaba bien, pero al ratar de invocarlo para obtener el valor me da un error de Promise { < pending > }

lo invoco de esta forma

```
let container = new contenedor('./productos.txt')
let productos =  container.getAll()
console.log(productos)
```

he intentado de muchas formas, creando una funcion async que la invoque, agregando el then pero no logro guardar la información en la variable. Soy nuevo con esto de async await y se me ha complicado bastante, espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos

Comment: El consolelog(productos) se ejecuta antes que la promesa se cumpla. El mismo deberia ir dentro de un then

Answer (score 0):

en base a lo que mencionas creo que este ejemplo te puede ayudar.

Asumo que tu archivo `productos.txt` luce así:

```
{"foo": "bar}
```

Tu clase sería algo así:

```
const fs = require('fs')

class Contenedor {
  constructor(archivo) {
    this.archivo = archivo
  }
  async getAll() {
    try {
      return await fs.promises.readFile(`./${this.archivo}`, 'utf-8')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

y entre las formas de usar tu clase podrían ser estas 2.

```
// using promises
let container = new Contenedor('./productos.txt')

container.getAll().then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

```
// using async/await en una IIFE
(async() => {
 let container = new Contenedor('./productos.txt')
 const response = await container.getAll();
 console.log(response)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque te falta un **`await`**.

Reescribe esto:

```
let productos = container.getAll()
```

De la siguiente forma:

```
let productos = await container.getAll()
```